# Linear Algebra Hoffman Kunze, Sec. 3.6 Exercise 17

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

Let W be the space of $n \times n$ matrices over the field F and let $W_0$ be the subspace spanned by the matrices of the form C=AB-BA. Prove that $W_0$ is exactly the subspace of the matrices which have trace zero.

Attempt:

If $C=AB-BA$, then since the $(i, j)^{th}$ entry of AB and BA are given by $(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (A)_{ik}(B)_{kj}, (BA)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (B)_{ik}(A)_{kj}$, where $(A)_{ij}$ and $(B)_{ij}$ denote the $(i, j)^{th}$ entry of A and B respectively, for every $i=1,2,...,n$, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(AB)_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (A)_{ik}(B)_{ki}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(B)_{ki}(A)_{ik}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(BA)_{kk}$$

And thus $tr(C)=tr(AB-BA)=tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0$.

If a matrix $C\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ has trace zero, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(C)_{ii}=0$ , where $(C)_{ij}$ is the $(i, j)^{th}$ entry of C.

Now we construct a basis for the matrices of the form $AB-BA$. Define matrices $E_{ij}$ in $M_n(\mathbb F)$ as follows: $(E)_{ij}=1$ for one specific pair of $(i,j)$, with all the other entries being $0$. Construct this for every pairof  $(i,j)$ to get $n^2$ matrices. However, we know that $tr(AB-BA)=0,$ so one of the matrices $E_{ii}$ is dependent on the other matrices of the form $E_{jj}$, where $i\ne j$. Without loss of generality, let such a matrix be $E_{11}$, so we have the basis 
$$\mathbb B=\{E_{ij}\mid i,j\in {\mathbb N}, 1\lt i\le n, 1\lt j \le n\}$$

There is a hint saying one could then construct linearly independent matrices of the form $AB-BA$, but I have no idea how to do that. Did I miss out on any other implied conditions?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that the subspace spanned by $AB-BA$ has trace $0$.
Conversely,
note for $i \neq j$ $$E_{ij}=E_{ii}E_{ij}-E_{ij}E_{ii} $$ and $$E_{ii}-E_{jj}=E_{ij}E_{ji}-E_{ji}E_{ij} $$  Thus, when viewed modulo the subspace spanned $$A=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}E_{ij} = \sum _{i}a_{ii} E_{11}  $$
If $A$ is in the subspace spanned then this sum is $0$ (modulo $W_0$) gives that the trace vanishes.

Comment: How did you get $E_{ij}=E_{ii}E_{ij}-E_{ij}E_{ii}$ and what do you mean by modulo? I computed $E_{ij}(I+E_{ii})=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (E)_{ik}(E)_{kj}=(E)_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+E_{ii})_{jk}=(E)_{ij}(E)_{jj}$. If i=j, this is $(E)_{ii}((E)_{ii}+1)$, otherwise it's $(E)_{ij}$. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: @Divide1918 Do you know what is a quotient space? Viewing modulo $W_0$ means we are looking at the quotient space $V/W_0$. By $E_{ij}$ I mean matrix which has $ij$th entry $1$ and all others are $0$.

Comment: Um I haven't learned about that, is it like quotient group?

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)

Comment: So how did you get the first equation?

Comment: Just compute and verify. In general $E_{ij}E_{kl}=\delta _{jk}E_{il} $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100792/discussion-between-divide1918-and-mathemather).